# Windows Laptop keeps stopping the WiFi after some time it's being locked

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

Okay here is my case, I have to connect remotely to my laptop from time to time and to do that it should be up and running but after 1-2 hours it looks like windows stops the network adapter and it doesn't have any internet connection and I cannot connect.

- In my power options I have chosen the option to never stop the
  networking adapters
- Also in the Power Plan Options I've seen in many sites that there
  should be some kind of "Network Power Management" where I should be
  able to tell it to not try to "Save power" by stopping the WiFi. I can't find any option like that even though I have installed the newest drivers.
- I have tried many different ways to make Windows stop doing this but they all fail

**So I decided to ask.**

Is it possible to create some kind of a scheduled "Task" that should run let's say every 1 hour just to keep my laptop "awake" so it won't stop the wi-fi adapter? And what would a script for that look like?

The thing is I don't know what makes Windows do that even after I set all possible options not to do it and that's why I don't know what type of script to search for.

**EDIT**: The Wireless adapter by itself seems to not have any power related options. I can't find any tabs that are about Power Options or if I click on "Advanced" tab in the "Configure" pop-up (for the given adapter) where there are a number of "properties" set, none of them is about power.

The only options I have set are Windows to never stop the Network adapters and to never let the laptop fall asleep while plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

There are several places to look to make sure your PC isn't trying to save power over your WiFi adapter.

In the adapter properties, as you already have, but also in Device Manager. Locate the line corresponding to your WiFi card, right-click on it, then choose Properties, Power Management, and uncheck the "Turn this device off to save power" (or some such thing; mine is in French...).

In the Advanced section of your adapter properties, there are several lines in the left pane, and you can set different values in a drop-down menu on the right.

If you find one called Leisure Power Save, make sure it's disabled.